# Mule - how long does SimpleMemoryObjectStore last?

Tags: mule, persistent-object-store

This is my use case: I want to store a flag and this flag should persist until the app is restarted. For example, if the app is crashed I want that flag to be reset.

Do you think if using `SimpleMemoryObjectStore` with `persistent` being `false` will work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SimpleMemoryObjectStore is not persistent by default:

```
@Override
26    public boolean More ...isPersistent()
27    {
28        return false;
29    }
```

So if the server is restarted, the value will be lost.

Comment: That's precisely what I want. I just want to make sure that it will be there throughout unless the app is restarted.

Comment: Yes it will be there throughout unless the app is restarted.